# How to filter the max value of a column in powerquery

Tags: powerquery

I´m trying to find a way to filter my (Semana) column by its MAX value, every week new data is added to my table and I just need to visualize the last week data.

I´ve tried Table.Max and List.Max but I can´t solve the problem

```
let
    Origen = Folder.Files("D:\DOCUMENTS\Cartera"),
    #"Personalizada agregada4" = Table.AddColumn(#"Tipo cambiado2", "MetaMora", each if [Días Atraso] <= 14 then 0 else [#"MORA CAP + INTS"]),
    #"Filas filtradas1" = Table.SelectRows(#"Personalizada agregada4", each ([Semana] = 30)) *** I change this value manually according to the max value in the table ***
in
    #"Filas filtradas1"
```

I need that the code automatically update the Max value from the [Semana] column.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
let
    Origen = Folder.Files("D:\DOCUMENTS\Cartera"),
    #"Personalizada agregada4" = Table.AddColumn(#"Tipo cambiado2", "MetaMora", each if [Días Atraso] <= 14 then 0 else [#"MORA CAP + INTS"]),
    max = List.Max(#"Personalizada agregada4"[Semana]),
    #"Filas filtradas1" = Table.SelectRows(#"Personalizada agregada4", each [Semana] = max)
in
    #"Filas filtradas1"
```